# Chat history of previous conversation with adaptive card inputs

Tags: bots, botframework, adaptive-cards, direct-line-botframework

How adaptive card user inputs can be shown in chat history of previous conversation?

If conversation happened with the user and the same user is back,they can see the chat history on webchat UI but the chat history is not displaying adaptive card user inputs.

Need solution to display what user has input or selected in adaptive cards as part of chat history.

Here is the API to get the history - POST /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/history

Comment: SO is NOT a coding service. We can only help you if you show code you have already written that has a specific problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have the API endpoint to get the conversation history. You can get the history back in JSON from that endpoint and then display it to the user however you want.